# Scala: How do I extract the first secound third and fourth byte from an integer using bit operators to binary and back?

Tags: scala, binary, integer, bit-manipulation

For example

-1234567890 = 10110110 01101001 11111101 00101110

10110110 = 182

01101001 = 105

11111101 = 253

00101110 = 46

I dont get how this should work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done exactly like in any other language, with bit shifts:

```
scala> val x = -1234567890
x: Int = -1234567890

scala> x & 0xFF
res0: Int = 46

scala> (x >> 8) & 0xFF
res1: Int = 253

scala> (x >> 16) & 0xFF
res2: Int = 105

scala> (x >> 24) & 0xFF
res3: Int = 182
```

Basically, you shift the value by the desired number of bytes to the right and then apply the mask to leave only the last byte:

```
0x000000FF == 0b00000000000000000000000011111111
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def getBinaryString(i: Int) = {
  val bs = i.toBinaryString
  val bs32 = if (bs.length == 32) bs else ("0" * (32 - bs.length)) + bs
  bs32
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

getBinaryString: (i: Int)String

scala> val i = -1234567890
i: Int = -1234567890

scala> val bs = getBinaryString(i)
bs: String = 10110110011010011111110100101110

scala> val first8 = bs.substring(0, 8)
first8: String = 10110110

scala> val first8Int = Integer.parseInt(first8, 2)
first8Int: Int = 182
```